# Changing the input frame rate of a series of images in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to animate a series of PNG images at 30 frames per second (and add an audio track) with FFmpeg.

On the command line, I specify the input and output frame rates as 30 fps.

> ffmpeg.exe **-r 30** -i %d.png -itsoffset 0.770 -i soundtrack.wav -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -y "ffmpegtest.mp4"

The output shows that it is reading the input images at the default **25 frames per second**.

```
    ffmpeg version N-82225-gb4e9252 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
      libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
      libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
      libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
      libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
      libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
      libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
      libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
    Input #0, image2, from '%d.png':
      Duration: 00:02:24.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 480x320, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

[I'll interrupt here to say it is that last line that confuses me]

```
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
    Input #1, wav, from 'soundtrack.wav':
      Duration: 00:06:51.26, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
        Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Output #0, mp4, to 'ffmpegtest.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 ( [0][0][0] / 0x0020), yuv420p, 480x320, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 mpeg4
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc57.66.101 aac
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
      Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [image2 @ 0000000000622cc0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
    frame= 3600 fps=242 q=19.1 Lsize=    9908kB time=00:06:52.04 bitrate= 197.0kbits/s speed=27.7x
    video:3263kB audio:6494kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.540179%
    [aac @ 000000000064e600] Qavg: 448.922
```

I am fairly new to FFmpeg. What am I missing? How do I tell it the input stream is 30 fps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With image sequences, you have to use the framerate option. So,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i %d.png -itsoffset 0.770 -i soundtrack.wav -vcodec mpeg4 -y "ffmpegtest.mp4"
```

With `-r` specified before the sequence name, FFmpeg assumes 25 fps and duplicates/drop frames to meet the set rate.

Comment: I don't completely understand the last sentence yet, but it solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: Let's say you set `-r 50`. FFmpeg treats the input as having a native rate of 25 and duplicates each frame to make it 50 fps. If you set `-r 10`, it drops 3 out of every 5 frames.

Comment: Right, I expected that to be true if I had the -r on the output only, and not on the input. I expected the first -r on the command line to affect the input, preventing that. (Clearly, I was wrong!) Looking at [section 5.5 of the manual](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), it seems it *used* to work they way I expected. Perhaps I got my misunderstanding from an old web-site. Thanks for clearing it up.